# Joomla 3 dropbox validation

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a dropdown that says Please Select.
I need the user to select an option before the form can be submitted.

I am using the

```
JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidator');
```

which is validating the text fields correctly.
Why isn't it validating the dropdown list.

```
<form id="mobile-search" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_boutiques_manager&view=boutiquesmobilesearch&Itemid='.$mitemid);?>" method="POST" class="mobile-search form-validate clearfix">

<div class="controls clearfix">
    <select class="required" title="County Dropdown" id="countyLocationMobile" name="mobile-county">
    <option value=" ">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Co. Antrim">Co. Antrim</option>
    <option value="Co. Armagh">Co. Armagh</option>
    <option value="Co. Carlow">Co. Carlow</option>
    <option value="Co. Cavan">Co. Cavan</option>
    <option value="Co. Clare">Co. Clare</option>
    <option value="Co. Cork">Co. Cork</option>
    <option value="Co. Derry">Co. Derry</option>
    <option value="Co. Donegal">Co. Donegal</option>
    <option value="Co. Down">Co. Down</option>
    <option value="Co. Dublin">Co. Dublin</option>
    <option value="Co. Fermanagh">Co. Fermanagh</option>
    <option value="Co. Galway">Co. Galway</option>
    <option value="Co. Kerry">Co. Kerry</option>
    <option value="Co. Kildare">Co. Kildare</option>
    <option value="Co. Kilkenny">Co. Kilkenny</option>
    <option value="Co. Laois">Co. Laois</option>
    <option value="Co. Leitrim">Co. Leitrim</option>
    <option value="Co. Limerick">Co. Limerick</option>
    <option value="Co. Longford">Co. Longford</option>
    <option value="Co. Louth">Co. Louth</option>
    <option value="Co. Mayo">Co. Mayo</option>
    <option value="Co. Meath">Co. Meath</option>
    <option value="Co. Monaghan">Co. Monaghan</option>
    <option value="Co. Offaly">Co. Offaly</option>
    <option value="Co. Roscommon">Co. Roscommon</option>
    <option value="Co. Sligo">Co. Sligo</option>
    <option value="Co. Tipperary">Co. Tipperary</option>
    <option value="Co. Tyrone">Co. Tyrone</option>
    <option value="Co. Waterford">Co. Waterford</option>
    <option value="Co. Westmeath">Co. Westmeath</option>
    <option value="Co. Wexford">Co. Wexford</option>
    <option value="Co. Wicklow">Co. Wicklow</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="mobile-search-submit-button" onclick="" type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using an XML file to define your form or manually building out the inputs and selects?

Comment: Are you saying you want it required or that you want the input validated?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting please select an option message because your default option values is not blank(`" "`) but there is an space in value.You have to change that to blank(`""`).

```
..
..
...
<div class="controls clearfix">
    <select class="required" title="County Dropdown" id="countyLocationMobile" name="mobile-county">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Co. Antrim">Co. Antrim</option>
    <option value="Co. Armagh">Co. Armagh</option>
.......
```